# Parameter estimation using data and model

Tags: maximum-likelihood, optimization

For the equation $A=Bw+C(1-w)$, I would like to find the most likely value for $w$.

Each coefficient A, B an C has an x and y coordinate and uncertainty (x,y; sd). For example, say I have the following points to work with:
A: (50,50; 2)
B: B1 (7,7; 2), B2 (6,6; 3), B3 (9,9; 1) and B4 (12,12; 4) 
C: C1 (81,81; 3), C2 (84,84; 2), C3 (82,82; 3), and C4 (90,90; 4).

Two ways of handling this problem have been suggested. The first is to minimize for w. The other is the find the MLE of w. My question is which is better and can you sketch out how to do it.

edit: In the relationship (x,y; sd) I mean (x+/-sd, y+/-sd) and w is a parameter (scalar) between 0 and 1 that I want to find the optimal/most likely value of given the data points I have.